# Map that associate a rating and a list of products java

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have products and each product have a rating.
What I tried is:

```
   public SortedMap<Double, List<String>> getProductsPerStars () {
            SortedMap<Double, List<String>> productsPerStars = new TreeMap<>();
            List<String> ps = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Product p : products.values()) {
                for(Rating r : ratings) {
                    System.out.println(r.getNumStars() + " " + r.getProductName());
                    if(r.getProductName() == p.getName()) {
                        System.out.println(this.getStarsOfProduct(p.getName()));
                        ps.add(p.getName());
//                  productsPerStars.put(key, value)

                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(ps);
            return productsPerStars;
        }
```

> The method getProductsPerStars() gives a map that associates the average number of stars with the list of product names that have this average, with the average values sorted in descending order and the names of the products sorted alphabetically. Products without reviews are discarded.

The output must look like this:

> {4.0=[p2], 2.0=[p0, p1]}

I think that is better to do this with streams... but I don't know how (because I have some errors...).
Can you please help me?

Comment: What errors do you have? Btw: you compare `String`s with `==`, dont do that.

Comment: I had errors when I tried to do with streams (I don't know how to use lamba function...)
Sorry for == 
But is not this the problem.

Comment: Ignore any possible solution with streams and do this manually. You never add your `ps` List to `productsPerStars`, why?

Comment: I have to make a list of products, then for each rating I have to associate a list of products and I don't know how...

Comment: Oops: `r.getProductName() == p.getName()` doesn't do what you hope it does. [Use `r.getProductName().equals(p.getName())` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Does `r.getNumStars()` return average rating?

Comment: `r.getNumStars()` returns the number of the stars for each product (not the average rating).

Comment: @OanceaCiprian what do you mean by an average then? based on what do you evaluate the average number for products?

Comment: if p1 has 3 and 5 stars, I must have {4.0 = [p1]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SortedMap<Double, List<String>> productsPerStars = new TreeMap<>(
    ratings.stream().collect(groupingBy(Rating::getNumStars, Rating:: getProductName))
);
```

Comment: *r.getNumStars() returns the number of the stars for each product (not the average rating)* from a comment.